# How can I save to shredpreferences if arraylist is null?

Tags: java, arraylist, sharedpreferences

Every time my Android app starts I get an `arraylist`, `MatchingArrayList`, from my server:

```
        try {
          JSONArray Object = new JSONArray(MatchingAsString);
          //for every object in the Array
          for (int x = 0; x < Object.length(); x++) {
            final JSONObject obj = Object.getJSONObject(x);
            MatchingArrayList.add(obj.getString("usernameMatch"));
            }
```

It looks something like this: `[+111, +222]`

Then I save the `arraylist` to `sharedpreferences` like this:

```
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesMAL = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorMAL = sharedPreferencesMAL.edit();
            Gson gsonMAL = new Gson();
            String jsonMAL = gsonMAL.toJson(MatchingArrayList);
            editorMAL.putString("MatchingArrayList", jsonMAL);
            editorMAL.commit();
```

So the next time the app is used, if `MatchingArrayList` has changed to `[+111, +222, +333]`, for instance, it will overwrite the last used `arraylist` of `[+111, +222]`

It works well except if `MatchingArrayList` is `null` or is empty. The `sharedpreferences` don't update. I tried:

```
          if (MatchingArrayList == null) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesMAL = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorMAL = sharedPreferencesMAL.edit();
            editorMAL.putString("MatchingArrayList", null);
            editorMAL.commit();
          } else {

            //save MatchingArrayList into sharedpreferences so we can use it elsewhere
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesMAL = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorMAL = sharedPreferencesMAL.edit();
            Gson gsonMAL = new Gson();
            String jsonMAL = gsonMAL.toJson(MatchingArrayList);
            editorMAL.putString("MatchingArrayList", jsonMAL);
            editorMAL.commit();

          }

  But still the last arraylist is being used. How can I fix this?
```

Comment: Simply check if MatchingArrayList is null or not before add to sharedpreferences. You can't add null to sharedpreferences. Add something instead.

Comment: I try that as mentioned in my question.

Comment: "editorMAL.putString("MatchingArrayList", null);" replace null with an empty string or whatever you like that you will know that it would mean null.

Comment: I did try "editorMAL.putString("MatchingArrayList", "");" but that didn't work either. I also tried with if (MatchingArrayList.isEmpty) { etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking at my java `arraylist` I checked my `response` for being empty on the `php` side from my app. Like this:

```
          if (response.isEmpty()) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesMatchingContactsAsArrayList = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorMatchingContactsAsArrayList = sharedPreferencesMatchingContactsAsArrayList.edit();
            editorMatchingContactsAsArrayList.putString("MatchingContactsAsArrayList", "");
            editorMatchingContactsAsArrayList.commit();
          } else {
```

That fixed my problem, updated the `sharedpreferences`.